Pattern Recognition Matrix: Waves with shapes
Why is the answer D? It's obvious that it should be D, E, or F, but why D?

Source: www.intelligencetest.com

Maybe

 Each row has one single, one double and one triple wave.

 Each shape (circle, square, triangle or lozenge) is present 3 times.


That's of course clear, and thats why it must be D, E or F and not A,B, C. The question is why $D$?

I updated my answer.
